# How can i Refresh the Listview with python gtk?

Tags: python, listview, treeview, gtk, refresh

i am new to python, I put a button to refresh the listview and get the information from a .txt file, but it doesn't works :(

Here is the code:

```
import gtk


actresses = [i.strip().replace("'", "").split() for i in open("lista.txt").readlines()]


class PyApp(gtk.Window): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_size_request(350, 250)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_title("ListView")

        self.Boton = gtk.Button("click")
        self.Boton.connect("clicked",self.create_list)

        self.Boton.show()

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 8)

        sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        sw.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN)
        sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

        vbox.pack_start(sw, True, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(self.Boton, True, True, 0)

        store = self.create_model()

        treeView = gtk.TreeView(store)
        treeView.connect("row-activated", self.on_activated)
        treeView.set_rules_hint(True)
        sw.add(treeView)

        self.create_columns(treeView)
        self.statusbar = gtk.Statusbar()

        vbox.pack_start(self.statusbar, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()


    def create_model(self):
        store = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)

        for act in actresses:
            store.append([act[0], act[1], act[2]])

        return store


    def create_columns(self, treeView):

        rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Nombre", rendererText, text=0)
        column.set_sort_column_id(0)    
        treeView.append_column(column)

        rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("apellido", rendererText, text=1)
        column.set_sort_column_id(1)
        treeView.append_column(column)

        rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Tamaño", rendererText, text=2)
        column.set_sort_column_id(2)
        treeView.append_column(column)


    def on_activated(self, widget, row, col):

        model = widget.get_model()
        text = model[row][0] + ", " + model[row][1] + ", " + model[row][2]
        self.statusbar.push(0, text)
    if model[row][0] == "lol":
       print "Funciona"

    def create_list(self, widget):
        # create a TreeView object which will work with our model (ListStore)
        self.listview = self.create_model()
        self.treeView = gtk.TreeView(self.listview)
        self.treeView.set_rules_hint(True)

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

First, the `create_model` method, called by `create_list`, is not re-reading the file, it is using the object initialized at top-level. To fix this, have `create_model` invoke the reading code.

More importantly, the `create_list` method is creating a new tree view, but isn't doing anything with it (other than storing it to a property of the Python instance). As far as the GTK window is concerned, your old tree view is still in the window. There are several ways to fix this:

1. As a quick fix, you can remove the existing tree view from the VBox, add the new one, and show it. A simpler version is to move the code that creates the vbox to a separate method, remove the vbox with `self.remove(self.get_child())` and re-add it. Either of these will accomplish what the code set out to do.
2. A better fix would be to only recreate the store and switch the tree view to the new store using the `set_model` method.
3. Another possibility is to empty the existing store and re-populate it. The tree view will react to the change to the store, and it is not necessary to call `set_model`, nor any other hint to the tree view.